# pig why it runs more than one mapreduce process?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I am having a complex pig script. From its logs i can see it spans 2 or 3  MR processes sequentially, depending on the data volume. (lets say, A & B)

PS: B triggered only after A is completed

Is this expected ? is there a way to find out which part of my pig script triggers which map reduce process ? 
My end goal is to optimize the pig script to run faster .

Simpler version of my task is as follows. This Pig script go through huge set of log files from different applications. For each log , it parses the data using regex and reports metrics like traffic count,avg resp time for various dimensions per hour

The code is really long and does multiple for-each with filters, one join & one big GROUP BY with multiple dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXPLAIN` to [view Pig's execution plan](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/test.html#explain) for your script. You will get output like this:

```
A = LOAD 'student' AS (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);

B = GROUP A BY name;

C = FOREACH B GENERATE COUNT(A.age);

EXPLAIN C;
-----------------------------------------------
Logical Plan:
-----------------------------------------------
Store xxx-Fri Dec 05 19:42:29 UTC 2008-23 Schema: {long} Type: Unknown
|
|---ForEach xxx-Fri Dec 05 19:42:29 UTC 2008-15 Schema: {long} Type: bag
etc ...  

-----------------------------------------------
Physical Plan:
-----------------------------------------------
Store(fakefile:org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage) - xxx-Fri Dec 05 19:42:29 UTC 2008-40
|
|---New For Each(false)[bag] - xxx-Fri Dec 05 19:42:29 UTC 2008-39
    |   |
    |   POUserFunc(org.apache.pig.builtin.COUNT)[long] - xxx-Fri Dec 05 
 etc ...  

--------------------------------------------------
| Map Reduce Plan                               
-------------------------------------------------
MapReduce node xxx-Fri Dec 05 19:42:29 UTC 2008-41
Map Plan
Local Rearrange[tuple]{chararray}(false) - xxx-Fri Dec 05 19:42:29 UTC 2008-34
|   |
|   Project[chararray][0] - xxx-Fri Dec 05 19:42:29 UTC 2008-35
 etc ...
```

Then, review the [Optimization Rules](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/perf.html#optimization-rules) and [Performance Enhancers](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/perf.html#performance-enhancers) for opportunities to tweak your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

this behaviour might be possible because your yarn container gets full, as you said you have large data set, so pig fires map reducers internally and each reduce task might be talking entire yarn container hence after successfully execution of 1 task rest task will get executed. you can check your MR job stats using ambari console (gui) or using command

```
hadoop job -list
```

or try
`yarn application -list` ( hadoop version 2.3 and above) 
this will show all job list and memory size each task allocated

for your second part of question i.e., for Pig script optimization

you can set mapreduce parallel property like

```
SET default_parallel XXX
```

where xxx is your number of reducers